# Knapsack Optimal Solution(Brute Force)

Tags: java, brute-force, knapsack-problem

The user will input the weight threshold, number of objects, and weight and cost of the 3 objects.
The output should be the Knapsack diagram and it should display the optimal solution.

The weight should be maximum and cost should be minimum.

Sample output:

```
w=60
n=3
w = 10
w2 = 35
w3 = 30
c=8
c1=4
c2=7

output:
A   10  8
B   35  4
C   30  7
AB  45  12
AC  40  15
BC  65  11
ABC 75  19

OPTIMAL SOLUTION: AB with total weight of 45 and total cost of 12.
```

My problem is my optimal solution is wrong. It outputs `OPTIMAL SOLUTION: A with total weight of 40 and total cost of 15.`

How should i fix it?

Thank you!

```
import java.util.*;
public class KnapsackBruteForce {
    static int numObject;
    static int weightThreshold = 0;
    static String variables[] = new String[100];
    static double numCombination;
    static KnapsackBruteForce knapsack = new KnapsackBruteForce();
    static Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
    public static void main(String args[]){
        System.out.print("Enter weight threshold: ");
        weightThreshold = input.nextInt();
        System.out.print("Enter number of objects: ");
        numObject = input.nextInt();

        int weightObject[] = new int[numObject+1];
        int costObject[] = new int[numObject+1];

        System.out.println("Enter variables: ");
        for(int i=0;i<numObject;i++){
            variables[i] = input.next();
        }
        for(int i=0;i<numObject;i++){
            System.out.print("Enter weight of object "+variables[i]+": ");
            weightObject[i] = input.nextInt();
        }
        for(int i=0;i<numObject;i++){
            System.out.print("Enter cost of object "+variables[i]+": ");
            costObject[i] = input.nextInt();
        }

        knapsack.possibleCombinations(variables, weightObject, costObject, weightThreshold, numObject);
    }

    public void possibleCombinations(String variables[], int weightObject[], int costObject[], int weightThreshold, int numObject){
        int weight = 0;
        int cost = 0;
        int optWeight = 0;
        int optCost = 0;
        String optVar = "";
        String newVar = "";

        for (int i = 1; i < (1 << numObject); i++) {
            String newVariable = Integer.toBinaryString(i);

            for (int j = newVariable.length() - 1, k = numObject - 1; j >= 0; j--, k--) {
                if (newVariable.charAt(j) == '1') {
                    newVar = variables[k];
                    weight += weightObject[k];
                    cost += costObject[k];
                    System.out.print(newVar);
                }
            }

            System.out.println("\t" + weight + "\t" + cost);

            if (weight <= weightThreshold) {
                if (optWeight == 0 && optCost == 0) {
                    optWeight = weight;
                    optCost = cost;
                } else if (optWeight <= weight) {
                    if (optCost <= cost) {
                        optVar = newVar;
                        optWeight = weight;
                        optCost = cost;
                    }
                }
            }

            weight = 0;
            cost = 0;
        }

        System.out.println("OPTIMAL SOLUTION: " + optVar + " with total weight of " + optWeight + " and total cost of " + optCost + ".");
    }
}
```

Comment: Add information logging to strategic places in your code or run it through a debugger to see at which point the algorithm isn't working like you think it should be working.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a priority issue in your logic, what if you have two bests 45 12 and 50 13 in your solution, which one would you choose?

And as a result of this ambiguity, in the below part you cannot choose:

```
            else if (optWeight <= weight) {
                if (optCost <= cost) {
                    optVar = newVar;
                    optWeight = weight;
                    optCost = cost;
                }
            }
```

Also even in your logic you should take lower cost not the higher `optCost <= cost`.

If you clear this ambiguity, the part you should focus is the part I mentioned.

Also use logging or at least print some info to console to see how your code behave.

Comment: thank you! It's now working. I removed the `optCost <= cost` condition.